# Internet Explorer UI issue

Tags: internet-explorer

We are facing an UI alignment  issue in Internet Explorer . We have a Dynamic HTML widget placed outside the form tag of page  as our HTML widget is also having its form tag and we know that form tag nesting is not possible.

Everything works fine on 100% zoom of the browser but alignment of this HTML widget gets distorted as we go on zoom in/ zoom out the screen.

We are using Jquery offset function to set top and left position of the widget but its not working fine only on  Internet Explorer.

Please provide any valuable suggestions/solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in Chrome too. Zooming is not reliable and it prone to mis-aligning elements, especially if you have percentage sizes or indeed any size that is not a multiple of 100 due to the zoom resulting in non-integer sizes.